# Haxe - Class overwrite at compilationtime

Tags: haxe

I'm trying to build a plugins architecture to my program in Haxe.
The way I see it is to clone packages in the plugin and overwrite the classes I want.

But I have one problem: **How do I tell the haxe compiler to use the plugin classes and not the core's?**

I was wondering about macros, but I'm not sure how to use them, so if there is an easier method, I'll be glad !

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I found out that you can use the classpath attribute of the compiler to do that:

```
-cp my/core/app  
-cp my/plugin
```

will give the expected result, the last one (plugin's classpath) being taken first.

Answer (score 2):

I made a Haxe framework that has a built-in PageComponent class that can be overridden by the presence of a properly-named class at compile time. When creating page instances my logic goes like this:

```
var class_name:String = "pages.P"+pageId;
var a_class = Type.resolveClass( class_name );
var s = ( a_class != null ) ? Type.createInstance( a_class,[] ) : new PageComponent();
```

Maybe you will find this to be helpful.

Comment: This is interesting but it'll limit the override capacity of plugins to PageComponent. But maybe it's safer than just overriding a class in a package. Maybe I'll do a mix.